# Chrome cant open profile with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

the profile - profile 2 isn't opening instead a guest tab is used, how to fix it to open profile specified in code

Answer (score 0):

```
chrom_options.add_arguments("user-data-dir=C:\\blabla\\User Data")

chrom_options.add_arguments("profile-directory=Profile 2")
```

user-data-dir considers profile as default , and you don't have to specify that . If its something else specify it through profile-directory argument